# Mostrar mensaje de vacio cuando no hay datos en foreach Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

una pregunta tonta pero que me está complicando, como evitar que me repita el mensaje de empty, en el siguiente código??

```
@foreach($contactos as $contacto)

        @forelse($contacto->contactos as $valor)

            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                <thead class="bg-white">
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">N°</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                    <th scope="col">Teléfono</th>
                    <th scope="col">Correo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Mensaje</th>
                    <th scope="col">Propiedad</th>
                    <th scope="col">Tiempo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                    <?php $counter=1;?>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="row"> <small> <?php echo $counter;?> </small></th>
                        <td> <small> {{ $valor->nombre }} </small></td>
                        <td> <small> {{ $valor->telefono }} </small></td>
                        <td> <small> {{ $valor->email }} </small></td>
                        <td class="text-justify"> <small> {{ $valor->mensaje }} </small></td>
                        <td> <a href="{{ url('detalle-propiedad/'.$contacto->slug_propiedad) }}" class="badge badge-primary">Ver propiedad</a> </td>

                        <td style="width: 12% !important"> <small>
                            <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-clock" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1a7 7 0 0 0 0 14zm8-7A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0z"/>
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.5 3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5.21l3.248 1.856a.5.5 0 0 1-.496.868l-3.5-2A.5.5 0 0 1 7 9V3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                            </svg>
                            {{ $valor->created_at->diffForHumans() }} </small>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <?php $counter++;?>
                </table>
            </div>

        @empty
            <p class="py-3 text-center">¡Aún no recibió contactos! </p>
        @endforelse
    @endforeach
```

Siempre me funcionó muy bien el **EMPTY** pero en este caso como tengo anidado los foreach me muestra varias veces el **EMPTY**. Entiendo el problema, como lo solucionarían o manejarían ustedes para que no se repita el mensaje?

Muchas gracias por su tiempo destinado en mi consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por ahora encontré que se le puede poner **@break**.

```
@empty
    <p class="py-3 text-center">¡Aún no recibió contactos! </p>
    @break 
@endforelse
```

¿Hay otra forma? le noto un poco rustico.

Comment: La directiva `forelse` trabaja como un `foreach` y un `if` juntos para recorrer y comparar si esta vacio o no. La solucion que le veo es esa, poner solo el `break` para romper ese ciclo https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops

Comment: A menos que crees tu mismo una condicional para hacer lo otro y obtener lo que quieres

Comment: Gracias Juan! a lo mejor había una forma más prudente, pero cumple con lo que requiero. Saludos